# Failed to resolve: play-services-tasks-license

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Gradle version is 4.4

Android Plugin Version 3.1.3

I hased tried to add maven in my project's build.gradle,  but it's failed

below is adding maven in my buid.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
       ....
       jcenter()
       google()
       maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
       ....
    }
}
```

I need your help, Thanks

Comment: No, it is not duplicate, I hased tried any way, but i am not success, i think not the same problem. please forgive me, thanks